# Groupby sum and count on multiple columns under multiple conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {
    "Type": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
    "Project": ["X123", "X123", "X21", "L31", "L31"],
    "Number": [100, 300, 100, 200, 500],
    "Status": ['Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I want to group by `Type` and get count and sum with several conditions and get results as follows:

```
Type  Total_Count  Total_Number  Count_Status=Y  Number_Status=Y  Count_Status=N  Number_Status=N 
 A        2          400              2               400              0               0
 B        5          800              1               200              2              600
```

I have tried following but not exactly what i need. Please share any ideas that you might have. Thanks!

```
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'Type', values = 'Number', aggfunc = np.sum)
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index = 'Type', values = 'Project', aggfunc = 'count')
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to create a Function:

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {
        'Total_Count': x['Type'].count(),
        'Total_Number': x['Number'].sum(),
        'Count_Status=Y': x[x['Status']=='Y']['Type'].count(),
        'Number_Status=Y': x[x['Status']=='Y']['Number'].sum(),
        'Count_Status=N': x[x['Status']=='N']['Type'].count(),
        'Number_Status=N': x[x['Status']=='N']['Number'].sum()}

    return pd.Series(names)

df.groupby('Type').apply(my_agg)

    Total_Count   Total_Number  Count_Status=Y  Number_Status=Y Count_Status=N  Number_Status=N
Type                        
A      2           400                2                400            0             0
B      3           800                1                200            2            600
```

Answer (score 4):

Start with `pivot_table`:

```
pv = (df.pivot_table(index='Type', 
                     columns='Status', 
                     values='Number', 
                     aggfunc='sum')
        .add_prefix('Number_Status='))

print(pv)
Status  Number_Status=N  Number_Status=Y
Type                                    
A                   NaN            400.0
B                 600.0            200.0
```

Next, `groupby`:

```
totals = df.groupby('Type').Number.agg([
    ('Total_Count', 'count'),  ('Total_Number', 'sum')])

print(totals)
      Total_Count  Total_Number
Type                           
A               2           400
B               3           800
```

Finally, status counts with OHEs:

```
cnts = (df.set_index('Type').Status
          .str.get_dummies()
          .sum(level=0)
          .add_prefix('Count_Status='))

      Count_Status=N  Count_Status=Y
Type                                
A                  0               2
B                  2               1
```

Putting it all together:

```
pd.concat([pv, totals, cnts], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

      Count_Status=N  Count_Status=Y  Number_Status=N  Number_Status=Y  \
Type                                                                                             
A                  0               2              NaN            400.0            
B                  2               1            600.0            200.0            

Total_Count  Total_Number
          2           400
          3           800
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing with

```
s1 = df.groupby('Type').Number.agg(['count', 'sum'])
s2 = df.groupby(['Type', 'Status']).Number.agg(['count', 'sum']).unstack(fill_value=0).sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
s2.columns = s2.columns.map('_Status='.join)
s1 = s1.add_prefix('Total_')
s = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
s
      Total_count  Total_sum  count_Status=N  sum_Status=N  count_Status=Y  \
Type                                                                         
A               2        400               0             0               2   
B               3        800               2           600               1   
      sum_Status=Y  
Type                
A              400  
B              200
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `margins` argument of `pd.pivot_table`. Drop the column total at the end as you only want row-wise margins.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Type', columns='Status', values='Number', 
                     aggfunc=['sum', 'count'], 
                     margins=True, 
                     margins_name='Total').fillna(0).drop('Total')
#          sum              count           
#Status      N      Y Total     N    Y Total
#Type                                       
#A         0.0  400.0   400   0.0  2.0     2
#B       600.0  200.0   800   2.0  1.0     3
```

If needed, rename the columns:

```
d = {'Y': 'Status=Y', 'N': 'Status=N', 'Total': 'Total'}
df1.columns = [f'{x}_{d.get(y)}' for x,y in df1.columns]
```

#### Output `df1`:

```
      sum_Status=N  sum_Status=Y  sum_Total  count_Status=N  count_Status=Y  count_Total
Type                                                                                    
A              0.0         400.0        400             0.0             2.0            2
B            600.0         200.0        800             2.0             1.0            3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply` to complete this task. For example, you can write a function to process your data on each column after getting Groupby object.

```
def compute_metrics(x):
    result = {'Total_Number': x['Number'].sum(), 'Count_Status=Y': len(x['Status'] == "Y")}
    return pd.Series(result)
```

Then the `df.groupby('Type').apply(compute_metrics)` will return the dataframe like this:

```
Type  Total Number Count_Status=Y
A     400          2             
B     800          3
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Cheers.